# Grep/Ack expression with parenthese and semicolon

Tags: vim, grep, ag

I'm using vim Ag.vim from [Silver Searcher](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher). I would like to search `let(:application` in my project.

If I do `:Ag "let(:application" app/` I get

```
|| ERR: Bad regex! pcre_compile() failed at position 16: missing )
|| If you meant to search for a literal string, run ag with -Q
```

No result with `Ag -Q "let(:application" app/`

Any idea of the right pattern ?

Comment: `:Ag 'let\(.......' dir/` should work.  `:Ag -Q "...."` works here too.

Comment: Why don't you use `grep` with the parameter `-F` (as per Fixed strings, instead of Regex)? --> `grep -F "let(:application"`

Comment: @fedorqui yep it works with grep. Thanks

Comment: Thanks @Kent `\` seems to do the trick.

Comment: Posted a [wiki] answer so that it is clear what solved your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either escape the `(`:

```
Ag 'let\(:application' app/
```

Or use `grep` with `-F` for fixed strings:

```
grep -F "let(:application" app/
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are confused by vim's magic pattern and ag's pattern:

The regex pattern parameter passed to `ag` does **NOT** follow your vim's `magic` setting.  By default ag applies `PCRE` so you have to escape `(` to let `ag` knows that you want to match `literal (`. Or you give `-Q` option to achieve the same goal.